# To restart WinRM services

Tags: windows, powershell, win32serviceutil

I was trying to restart winRM services in multiple servers, but am getting below error can I get suggestions.

```
Restart-Service -ComputerName (Get-Content G:\12282019\Servers.txt) -ServiceName WinRM
```

error:

> Restart-Service : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
>   name 'ComputerName'. At line:1 char:17
>   + restart-service -ComputerName (Get-Content G:\12282019\Servers.txt) - ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Restart-Service], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand

Answer (score 4):

`Restart-Service` doesn't have a `ComputerName` parameter - See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-service?view=powershell-6) for the Microsoft document. The easiest option would be:

`Get-Service -ComputerName HOST_NAME -Name WinRM | Restart-Service`

Here is [an article](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/01/15/startingstopping-and-restarting-remote-services-with-powershell/) that goes into more depth